# Error en System.Windows.Forms.Control.inCrossThreadSafeCall

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas,
Tengo una aplicación que en un momento dado lanza un Thread, dentro de ese Thread se llama a un control del usuario donde se pone una imagen en un boton dentro del control de usuario.

El control de usuario tiene una lista de Tuplas compuestas por un TextBox y un Boton, para de esta forma saber que Boton esta asociado a cada TextBox.

El problema lo tengo cuando intento buscar dentro de esa lista de tuplas a que boton hay que ponerle la imagen.

Os pongo el codigo utilizado:

La parte donde se crea el Thread para que se ejecute en segundo plano:

```
 Thread preparaPDF = new Thread(() => lanzaComprobacionPDFIndividual(idActual));
                preparaPDF.IsBackground = true;
                preparaPDF.Start();
```

Dentro de lanzaComprobacionPDFIndividual se llama al control de usuario visorPDF:

```
visorPDF.anadeFichero(listaIDs[idActual], ficG, true);
```

y la funcion donde me da el error, es en anadeFichero

```
 public void anadeFichero(string id, string ruta, bool bueno)
    {
        try
        {
            Button b = (Button)listaRelacionada.Find(x => (x.Item1 as TextBox).Text == id).Item2;
            if (b != null)
            {
                b.Tag = ruta;
                habilitaBoton hab = new habilitaBoton(enableBoton);

                b.Invoke(hab, b, bueno);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

De hecho le he puesto un try catch por si lanzase una excepcion pero no lanza nada, se queda parado alli.

Me resulta muy extraño este error ya que como se ve en listaRelacionada si que hay valores.

A continuacion os pongo un pantallazo de como se ve en debug.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No he revisado todo tu código, pero en casi todos estos casos el problema suele ser tratar de acceder a controles del UI desde un hilo que no es el principal,algo que no está permitido. Por otro lado, no useis la clase Thread. Es complicada de manejar y hay alternativas mejores como `BackGroundWorker`  y `Task`

Comment: @Pikoh si, tendre que hacerlo de otra manera, pero he usado Invoke para tocar lo que es referente a la UI. Es que me llama la atencion que falle al buscar en una lista de tuplas que no tiene nada especial

Comment: Como estás cargando `listarelacionada`? Me temo que lo que se están guardando son referencias a los botones, con lo cual a pesar de que no accedes directamente al ui sino a la lista, en realidad si que accedes.

Comment: @Pikoh pues la cargo asi listaRelacionada.Add(new Tuple<Control, Control>(t, b)); siendo t un textbox y b un boton

Comment: Eso en realidad no guarda el control, sino una referencia al mismo. Por eso te falla, tal vez usando Invoke tambien para acceder a esa lista lo soluciones

Comment: @Piko muchas gracias por la ayuda, lo intentare, es la primera vez que uso tuplas y se nota XD

Comment: En realidad no es un problema de usar tuplas. Aunque hubieses usado un simple `List` te sucedería lo mismo, ya que un control entiendo que siempre se va a almacenar por referencia :)

Comment: Usar tuplas no es como mucho para este caso? es mas, para evitar acceder a la UI, no convendria que tuvieras una clase que contenga la info del boton, actualizar la clase, y despues en el thread principal actualizar los botones que correspondan?

Comment: hola @gbianchi El tema es que se trata de un control de usuario en el que en tiempo de ejecucion se añaden textbox asociados a un boton, en el textbox esta un identificador, y en el tag del boton se guarda la ruta donde esta el fichero que se visualiza cuando se hace click. y este es el problema que tengo, que tengo que habilitar y poner una imagen al boton u otra en funcion de un fichero q se va generando (lo genera una maquina). Por esto q tengo que lanzar este proceso en otro hilo para no bloquear la aplicacion y al tener que hacer cambios en el control de usuario pierdo el hilo principal.

Comment: Pero si estas cambiando la interface.. no necesitarias bloquear la UI? o por lo menos, hacerlo de alguna forma que no parezca bloqueada (una barra de progreso?) pero esta bloqueada? o le dejas apretar otros botones y hacer otras cosas?

Comment: @gbianchi Si, se me queda bloqueada la aplicacion o directamente se cierra... estoy probando a ver si encuentro alguna manera. con lo que sea ya lo pondre por si le puede servir a alguien

Comment: @Veelicus recuerda que puedes responder tu propia pregunta con la solución que encontraste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, he conseguido solventar este tema de la siguiente manera:
En vez de estar con un proceso en background, thread o task mirando cuando se genera el pdf, lo hago mediante un timer que comprueba cada 500 milisegundos si el fichero se ha generado, una vez encontrado el fichero, para modificar la interfaz grafica del contro de usuario he adecuado una clase que he encontrado en Stackoverflow ingles, que a continuacion os pongo:

```
  public static class ThreadHelperClass
{
    delegate void SetTextCallback(UserControl f, Control ctrl, string ruta, bool bueno, Bitmap imagen);
    /// <summary>
    /// Set text property of various controls
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="form">The calling form</param>
    /// <param name="ctrl"></param>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    public static void activarBoton(UserControl form, Control ctrl, string ruta, bool bueno, Bitmap imagen)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the 
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread. 
        // If these threads are different, it returns true. 
        if (ctrl.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(activarBoton);
            form.Invoke(d, new object[] { form, ctrl, ruta, bueno, imagen });
        }
        else
        {
            ctrl.Enabled = true;
            ctrl.Tag = ruta;
            ctrl.BackgroundImage = imagen;

        }
    }
```

Luego, en vez de buscar el boton en la lista de controles donde esta y crear una copia de el, lo utilizo directamente de la siguiente manera:

```
ThreadHelperClass.activarBoton(this, listaControles[i] as Button, rutaEnCurso, resultadoEnCurso, bit);
```

siendo rutaEnCurso la ubicacion del pdf, resultadoEnCurso si el resultado de la prueba ha sido bueno o no y bit el bitmap que se pasa al boton.

Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda y las ideas.